# How to wrap divs with brackets using CSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue and Vuetify in an RTL app. I'm trying to create the following layout:

[image]

Basically you have two brackets that wrap a text and three buttons (each leads to different locations but currently I used the same button for simplicity).

What I currently got:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-model="showModal"
    @click:outside="handleClose"
    outlined
    width="750"
  >
    <v-card>
      <div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">{</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 34%;">
          <p>TEXT</p>
          <div>
            <v-btn fab dark target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              <v-icon>mdi-hand-heart-outline</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn fab dark :target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              <v-icon>mdi-linkedin</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn fab dark target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              <v-icon>mdi-github</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">}</div>
        <br style="clear: left;" />
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

What I got:

[image]

Having trouble designing this template. How can I make the brackets bigger with a fixed size that always matches the size of the text and the buttons? Also, not sure why, he left bracket looks to the other side (guessing due to RTL).

Comment: Don't use floats for this. use flexbox. Also don't use Text for this, use `:before` and `:after` css selectors for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ::before and ::after for the brackets.
I'm not sure about the size of the brackets but you can adjust them depending of the screen size with media queries.

```css
.container::before{
  content:"{";
  font-size:5rem;
}
.container::after{
  content:"}";
  font-size:5rem;
}
.content{
  display:inline-block;
}
.text{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>b</button>
      <button>c</button>
      <div class="text">Hi</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know why it adds a space above the brackets "{" and "}"? Tried to increase the size of them and it keeps that space above them. Try inspect it to see what I'm talking about

Comment: Just to make it more clear, please see here what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF6W3.png

Comment: You can try to add "vertical-align: text-bottom" on the before and after pseudo elements.
It seems that brackets have space on top of them so it will make some space on top of the div apparently. https://imgur.com/a/6S9Gt1f

Comment: It didn't help. Looks like it's something related to the fonts (?) which in my case I use `sans serif`. I also tried with others such as `Roboto`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using plain text for the brackets could be an inline svg as so:

```css
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
.brackets {
  display: flex;
}
.brackets::before, .brackets::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.brackets::after {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="brackets">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar</button>
    <button>Baz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since it's an RTL app, I get brackets facing other ways. How can it be fixed?

Comment: @vesii Change the CSS selector that has the "transform" from "::after" to "::before"